# How to turn a chosen select/option field in jsp into a variable without submitting a form?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, jstl, uri

I have a basic select in jsp

```
<select name="tableName">
    <c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                                       
        <option><c:out value="${valuesInRow}"></c:out></option>                          
    </c:forEach>
</select>
```

then I want to pass it like this:

```
<s:url var="url_list" value="/spravochnik/list">
    <s:param name="tableName" value="${tableName}"/>
</s:url> 
<a href="${url_list}">List</a>
```

The controller accepts tableName like this:

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/list", method = { RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET })
    public String getSpravochniks(Model m, @PathVariable("tableName") String tableName) {
...
}
```

In the browser I see the URL form like this:

```
http://localhost:8080/spravochnik/list?tableName=
```

so it doesn't recognize the tableName variable I chose from the select... I am not using form and submit, I want to connect solely with the url. Please, can you help me identify why the tableName doesn't get passed?

**EDIT:**
Now my jsp part looks like this:

```
<c:set var="tableName" value="${0}"></c:set>
<select name="tableName">
<c:forEach var="dropDown" items="${dropDown}">
<c:forEach var="valuesInRows" items="${dropDown.valuesInRows}">
<c:forEach var="valuesInRow" items="${valuesInRows}" varStatus="loop">                                        
<c:if test="${loop.index %2 != 0}">
<c:set var="tableName" value="${valuesInRow}"></c:set>
<option value="${valuesInRow}"><c:out value="${valuesInRow}"></c:out></option>
</c:if>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
</select>
```

This is a real, non-simplified version. I populate the select from db. When I check my tableName variable i set in c:set it always shows the last option. How to make it show the selected option instead?

Comment: `tableName` is a query parameter, use `@RequestParam` instead of `@PathVariable`

Comment: Thank you! Now I've done it and I'll edit the post as something has come up

Comment: Edited the post, added more info

Comment: First of all you got two different request methods in your controller `RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.GET` doesn't this give you an error?

Comment: Also, what exactly does the `<s` tag does? Is it a custom jstl tag?

Comment: It's <spring:something, I just don't like to write Spring, it's from `<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>`